# MyBatis 'or' criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis, mybatis-generator

```
select
    *
from person
WHERE (id like '%test%'
   or name like '%test%' 
    or location like '%test%'
 )
 and date >= '2019-10-24 00:00:00'
 and date < '2019-10-26 00:00:00'
```

How could I construct that with Criteria objects?

```
MyExample example = new MyExample();
MyExample.Criteria criteria = example.createCriteria();
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of query is not easy with the older generator runtime. You will need to think of your query a bit differently to make it work. For example with boolean algebra you can say that...

```sql
(a | b | c) & d & e
```

is functionally equivalent to

```sql
(a & d & e) | (b & d & e) | (c & d & e)
```

Writing where conditions with the second form is possible with the old runtime, but this is really ugly.

I would suggest that you change to using the newer MyBatis3DynamicSQL runtime to generate your code. With that new runtime you can write the where clause exactly as you want it to be. See these pages for more information about the new runtime:

- http://mybatis.org/generator/generatedobjects/dynamicSql.html
- https://mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/docs/introduction.html